# change the TreeView dotted to different design

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I'm using the telerik TreeView.

I wonder if there is a way to change the dotted line used in the TreeView to a line that is not dotted(by uploading a background image file,or if telerik a have another solution.

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/treeview/draganddrop?theme=default

Answer (score 0):

Based on your Theme please update below highlighted (three) images.

[image]

If you used CDN URL then please create this three images and add into your project.
Then copy all the css class which was used this three images.
Then update the image source and add "!important" in the style property.

Code from Original CSS File (ehich was used 'treeview-nodes.png' image)

```
.t-treeview-lines .t-top,.t-treeview-lines .t-mid,.t-treeview-lines .t-bot{background-image:url('Default/treeview-nodes.png')}
```

Updated CSS code

```
.t-treeview-lines .t-top,.t-treeview-lines .t-mid,.t-treeview-lines .t-bot{background-image:url('YourNewPathComesHere') !important;}
```